# How to delete variable number of rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

Table structure

```
------------
Transaction
------------
id      INT PrimaryKey
user_id INT ForeignKey
amount  INT

------------
User
------------
id      INT PrimaryKey
number  INT
```

Transaction table contains multiple rows for each user, number of rows is stored in User.number (which is not same for every user) 
Due to some bug in the program some extra rows has been created in Transaction table without increment User.number 
Now I have to remove those extra rows from Transaction table.

As far as I know, to remove last 10 rows in Transaction table, I can run

```
DELETE * from Transaction ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Is there any way to delete variable number of rows for different users in single SQL query?

Comment: Well I may be missing something here, but if the ones without a usernumber are a problem, why don't you delete the ones without a usernumber???

Comment: If I correctly understand your questions you have users in the database that have a number of 5 but 8 transactions in the transaction table. How do you know which of the rows you need to remove from the transaction table? Is it the ones with the highest ids?

Comment: Oh and if you are going to do Delete * from SomeTable Limit 10, put an order by in there

Comment: Having a static value on total number of transactions in a column is a bad design.

Comment: The DELETE statement you posted won't remove the last ten rows. It will remove an arbitrary ten rows. You need to decide on the criteria for which rows you want to delete and express that in a WHERE clause.

Comment: @scraatz Yes I want to delete the ones with highest id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by generating a SQL script to remove the additional transactions:

You should be able to find the users with:

```
SELECT user.id AS user_id, COUNT(transaction.id)-user.number AS num_trans FROM user, transaction WHERE user.id=transaction.user_id GROUP BY user.id, user.number HAVING user.number < COUNT(transaction.id)
```

Create a view from this select statement:

```
CREATE VIEW invalidusers AS
SELECT user.id AS user_id, COUNT(transaction.id)-user.number AS num_trans FROM user, transaction WHERE user.id=transaction.user_id GROUP BY user.id, user.number HAVING user.number < COUNT(transaction.id)
```

Check the output from this view.

Now select a script to execute from this view:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DELETE * FROM transaction WHERE user_id=', CONVERT(user_id, CHAR), ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ', CONVERT(num_trans, CHAR), ';') AS CMD from invalidusers
```

The last command generates the script you can run to remove the transaction for all users.